# Aiohttp - should I keep the session alive 24/7 when polling restful api?

Tags: python, aiohttp

Sorry, library first-timer here. I am polling a restful endpoint every 10 seconds. 
Its not obvious to me which of the following is appropriate:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def poll(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            return await r.text()

async def main():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print(await poll('http://example.com/api'))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Or the session variable persists forever:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def poll(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        async with session.get(url) as r:
            print(await r.text())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(poll('http://example.com/api'))
loop.run_forever()
```

I expect the latter is desirable, but coming from the non-asynchronous requests library, I'm not used to the idea of sessions. Will I actually experience faster response times because of connection pooling or other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official document:

> Don’t create a session per request. Most likely you need a
>   session per application which performs all requests altogether.
>
> A session contains a connection pool inside. Connection reusage and
>   keep-alives (both are on by default) may speed up total performance.

Surely the latter one is better and definitely you will have a faster experience.